# LeetCode Question - 2634. Filter Elements from Array

Tags: javascript, distinct-values

When I try to run this code without the Number(), it doesn't work.

```
ar filter = (arr, fn) => {
 let filteredArr = [];

   for(const i in arr){

      if(fn(arr[i], Number(i)))  filteredArr.push(arr[i])
      
   }

return filteredArr;
};
```

I don't understand why this code doesn't work without the Number(), if the index is some number, at least 0, it's a integer, then it should work... Could you help me? I would be really grateful.

Comment: how are you calling `filter`? what is the value of `fn`? hint: object property names are always type `String`

Comment: Are you sure it does not work? It looks good to me. What kind of error do you have

Comment: @Daniel Cruz When I tried, it returns: var i should be a integer. Apparently, when we use for(const i in arr), it treats it like an object, so this array becomes something like    
  { "0": "Value", "2": "ValueTwo" }, then i == String.

Comment: @Jaromanda X It's a leetCode problem,                                                       
Input: arr = [0,10,20,30], fn = function greaterThan10(n) { return n > 10; }
Output: [20,30]
Explanation:
const newArray = filter(arr, fn); // [20, 30]
The function filters out values that are not greater than 10.                                                    leetcode.com/problems/filter-elements-from-array

Comment: I am very grateful for the help of all of you, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop iterates over enumerable string properties. All the indexes used to access elements of an array are such properties, so you need to convert each index to a number when iterating with `for (const i in arr)`.

Note that it is generally a very bad idea to use this form of loop when you want to access indexes. If you cannot use `Array#filter`, you could use `Array#forEach` which passes the index to its callback, or a standard index-based `for` loop.

```js
arr.forEach((x, i) => {
    if (fn(x, i)) filteredArr.push(x);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you use for...in:

```
var filter = (arr, fn) => {
    let filteredArr = [];
    for(const i in arr){
        console.log(typeof i)
        if(fn(arr[i], Number(i)))  filteredArr.push(arr[i])
    }
    return filteredArr;
};
```

This loop is used for objects and is not recommended for arrays.

You can try to use the loop for that consists of three optional expressions:

```
var filter = (arr, fn) => {
    let filteredArr = [];
    for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        if(fn(arr[i], i))  filteredArr.push(arr[i])
    }
    return filteredArr;
};
```